# How to manually change Avada theme copyright year in the footer?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I tried to modify the year of the copyright text placed in the footer of the page by placing the function below in the file called *functions.php*. However, the code placed the copyright in the middle of the page with a different format, and kept the old copyright info.

I used this code:

```
add_action( 'avada_footer_copyright_content', 'modify_avada_footer_copyright_content' );

function modify_avada_footer_copyright_content() {
echo 'This is my copyright text';
}
```

While I understand that the copyright text can be modified through Avada -> Theme Options, this is not an alternative in my case. I need to be able to change the year specified within the copyright text manually.

I also tried to find this info in the database, but it seems like there are many posts that do not store the information plainly.

Finally, the file footer.php allows me to delete the copyright info, but not to update the year, as I need.

Any help is greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Can you show the code in footer.php?

Comment: Please add your footer.php file code here

Comment: I just posted the code in footer.php

Comment: Su, Developerme, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code in footer.php

```
    <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
        <div class="wrap">
            <?php
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/footer/footer', 'widgets' );

            if ( has_nav_menu( 'social' ) ) : ?>
                <nav class="social-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Footer Social Links Menu', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?>">
                    <?php
                        wp_nav_menu( array(
                            'theme_location' => 'social',
                            'menu_class'     => 'social-links-menu',
                            'depth'          => 1,
                            'link_before'    => '<span class="screen-reader-text">',
                            'link_after'     => '</span>' . twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'chain' ) ),
                        ) );
                    ?>
                </nav><!-- .social-navigation -->
            <?php endif;

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/footer/site', 'info' );
            ?>
        </div><!-- .wrap -->
    </footer><!-- #colophon -->
</div><!-- .site-content-contain -->
```